# Get Cell DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have this message when I click into `dgv` to get `data cell`:

> """"L'index était hors limites. Il ne doit pas être négatif et doit
>   être inférieur à la taille de la collection. """"

the problem is in the line 6 wish start with : `comboBox1.Text = dgv.........`

```
    private void dgv_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex < 0)
            return;
        textBox1.Text = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value + "";
        comboBox1.Text = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value + "";
        comboBox2.Text = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value + "";
        comboBox3.Text = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value + "";
        comboBox4.Text = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value + "";
    }
```

Comment: How many columns are available in your grid?

Comment: all column (14) to import them from my databas it's done !!! the problem is in the event when i click into dgv !!

Comment: I can only suggest to check with the debugger how many columns are present. Put a breackpoint on the line before the failing one and check the value for `dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells.Count`

Comment: In runtime, using the debugger, check if row `dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex]` has 3 cells or more.

Comment: I find it !!! it was in TexBox which get twice of time the same line from the DataTable one time automatically from My code the second when I click into datagridview.
Thank you any way for your help :)